# Get rid of Java exceptions when I am sure the exception will not happen

Tags: java, exception

Please see the code below. IDE forces me to deal with the `NoSuchAlgorithmException`. However for my case, I am explicitly using the 'NativePRNGNonBlocking' algorithm for creating randomness, therefore guarantee the exception will not occur. Is there an elegant way to get rid of the exception handling for this case?

```
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Randomness {

    private static String algorithm = "NativePRNGNonBlocking";

    private static SecureRandom getSecureRandom() {
        try {
            SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom().getInstance(algorithm);
            return secureRandom;
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static byte[] createRandomBytes(int byteLength) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[byteLength];
        getSecureRandom().nextBytes(buffer);
        return buffer;
    }

}
```

Any helps are highly appreciated!

Comment: What you have looks fine to me.

Comment: That methods signature says it can throw such exception. One day NativePRNGNonBlocking could no longer exist and this exception is thrown. Maybe you convert it to user input, and there is a typo. If you really want, however, just name your "e" to ignored, and leave your catch block empty. That's not your IDE forcing you btw :) that is the compiler. Your IDE is saving you the time of the program failing to compile

Answer (score -1):

[Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) has an annotation useful for this. `@SneakyThrows` (https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows)

This would make your code look a little cleaner.

```
@SneakyThrows(NoSuchAlgorithmException.class)
private static SecureRandom getSecureRandom() {
   return SecureRandom().getInstance(algorithm);
}
```